# Executing a child script with multiple stdin stdout

Tags: python, stdout, stdin

I'm trying to create a python script in windows that runs another python script that contains an unknown number of inputs and outputs and captures the stdout

I was wondering what the best method would be. I have tried `communicate()` but it runs to the end of the file and doesn't work properly with a second input.

Comment: I don't understand what "I was wondering what the best method would be. I have tried communicate() but it runs to the end of the file and doesn't work properly with a second input." means. Does your second python script take multiple arguments?

Comment: instead of `process.communicate()`, `process.stdin.write('something') and process.stdin.flush()` might help